# SQL error 1072 doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

```
   create table have(
       roomnb1 int not null,
       brname1 char(20) not null,
       id1 int not null,
       viewtype char(20) not null,
       primary key(roomnb1,brname1,id1,viewtype)
   )engine=innodb;

   alter table has
   add constraint fk_has_room foreign key(roomnb1,brname1,id1)
       references room(roomnb,brname,id),
   add constraint fk_has_view foreign key(viewtype)
       references view (viewtype);
```

I'm getting the error:

> key column 'roomnb1' doesn't exist in table

But how is that?

Comment: `alter table has`.  What is table `has`?  The create table is for `have`.

Comment: omg didnt see that tysm :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff the wrong thing in the other post ,was that i didnt put them in order like parent first then child